Como puedo filtrar todos los array que tengan su clave string dentro de otro array
// Array original
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2060352479001F0010000000272] => Array
                (
                    [Ruc] => 20603524790
                    [Razon Social] => IO SOLUTIONS S.A.C.
                    [Periodo] => 202405
                    [CAR SUNAT] => 2060352479001F0010000000272
                    [Fecha de emisión] => 16/05/2024
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2060352479001F0010000000273] => Array
                (
                    [Ruc] => 20603524790
                    [Razon Social] => IO SOLUTIONS S.A.C.
                    [Periodo] => 202405
                    [CAR SUNAT] => 2060352479001F0010000000273
                    [Fecha de emisión] => 16/05/2024
                )

        )

)

// Array a obtener
Array
(
   
            [2060352479001F0010000000272] => Array
                (
                    [Ruc] => 20603524790
                    [Razon Social] => IO SOLUTIONS S.A.C.
                    [Periodo] => 202405
                    [CAR SUNAT] => 2060352479001F0010000000272
                    [Fecha de emisión] => 16/05/2024
                )



            [2060352479001F0010000000273] => Array
                (
                    [Ruc] => 20603524790
                    [Razon Social] => IO SOLUTIONS S.A.C.
                    [Periodo] => 202405
                    [CAR SUNAT] => 2060352479001F0010000000273
                    [Fecha de emisión] => 16/05/2024
                )

)

He llegado con esta linea de codigo a obtener lo que quiero pero solo obtengo un elemento con la variable $csvFile[2], pero no puedo recoreger todas las demas.
return array_filter(
  $csvFile[2],
  function ($k) {
    return is_string($k);
  },
  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);


Podrías utilizar array_reduce para iterar el arreglo original e ir extrayendo los datos de éste en un nuevo.
Ejemplo:
$newData = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $item) {
    return $carry = $carry + $item;
}, []);

Resultado:
Array
(
    [2060352479001F0010000000272] => Array
        (
            [Ruc] => 20603524790
            [Razon Social] => IO SOLUTIONS S.A.C.
            [Periodo] => 202405
            [CAR SUNAT] => 2060352479001F0010000000272
            [Fecha de emisión] => 16/05/2024
        )

    [2060352479001F0010000000273] => Array
        (
            [Ruc] => 20603524790
            [Razon Social] => IO SOLUTIONS S.A.C.
            [Periodo] => 202405
            [CAR SUNAT] => 2060352479001F0010000000273
            [Fecha de emisión] => 16/05/2024
        )

)

Demo

Muchas gracias Marcos por tu ayuda era lo que necesitaba, que tengas buen dia.

Buenas noches Marcos acepte la respuesta, no encuentro la opción para realizar una votación
